# How do I get a multi line in GXT ToolTipConfig?

Tags: gxt

How do I get a multi line in GXT ToolTipConfig?

I have a long Text in the ToolTipConfig's title. How can I break it to multi line?

Comment: u can split the text by using "\n".where ever u needed u can use it.

Comment: <br> helps. You would need to inject a <br> into your string in a for loop executing some condition. This condition might have to change with your widgets size. Wordwrap helps you break up your string according to your widgets width ( automagically without ever needing to change code!!! )

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up this wordwrap css property attribute to the ToolTip titles html tag.

```
div.test {word-wrap:break-word;}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: Thx, I had found how to get a multi line .
use '<br/>'.

Comment: <br> helps. You would need to inject a <br> into your string in a for loop executing some condition. This condition might have to change with your widgets size. Wordwrap helps you break up your string according to your widgets width ( automagically without ever needing to change code!!! )

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you need:

```
ToolTipConfig config = new ToolTipConfig();
config.setMaxWidth(300);
```

So, the tooltip will move the lines for you.